# tinyMCE problems editing XML tags

Tags: xml, tinymce, editing

I am trying to use tinyMCE to edit and save some text that includes XML tags.
When I try to save the text, some information gets lost.

For example, if the text I'm trying to same is 
First Name 
at the first save is saved correctly, if I try to edit the  tag will be lost.
This happens only if the  tag is placed at the end of the sentence.
Also, sometimes it gets saved but doesn't display only if I hit edit again.

My editor is initialized as:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,indent,outdent,separator,undo,redo,first_name",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    convert_newlines_to_brs : true,
    convert_fonts_to_spans : false,
    valid_elements : '*[*]',
    //    media_strict: false,
    //    encoding : "xml",
    inline_styles: false,
    verify_html : false,
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.addButton('currentyear', {
            title : 'Tag to be replaced with the current year',
            image : 'pages/images/ed_tag_current_year.gif',
            onclick : function() {
                ed.focus();
                ed.selection.setContent('&lt;first_namer&gt;');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you could have a closer look at the tinymce config option valid_elements and valid_children

Comment: possible duplicate of [TinyMCE text editor is not loading my text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607993/tinymce-text-editor-is-not-loading-my-text)