# TinyMCE text editor is not loading my text

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in my page but it's not loading the required Html text.
I have created the this text dynamically in Javascript using following code but after using TinyMCE text editor, The text is not loaded inside TinyMCE text editor.

> $('#mytextAreaID').Text(htmlcode);

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following thread helped me to resolve this issue:

[TinyMCE not grabbing content from textarea before hiding that textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716667/tinymce-not-grabbing-content-from-textarea-before-hiding-that-textarea)

> `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'editor1');`